# Finding the Machine Name of an Module-based Field Added to $content variable

Tags: nodes

I need to edit a field added to my $content variable by a contrib module called Print, email, and PDF versions. It creates a link at the top of the content region that says 'Print PDF' and prints a PDF of the page. I've looked everywhere in the admin settings for the module for this information but can't find it anywhere.

Note: I've tried looking in my DB and trying what I found in there for the field, with no luck. I also tried using var_dump but that doesn't help me. I looked in the print.module file but wasn't seeing anything in there, although to be fair it's quite voluminous so I might have missed something.

I'm trying to access it and hide it through code in node--resource.tpl.php so I can manipulate it independently of the rest of the vars in $content. This is the code I'm using successfully to hide OTHER items in $content for example:

```
// #nomarkup is a function defined in template.php
$content['field_body']['#theme'] = "nomarkup";
hide($content['field_body']);
```

With Firebug, the DOM shows  followed by  for the PRINT PDF link I want to hide, but neither of those seems to be recognized when I try to hide them using a similar format as the other items in $content, like so:

```
$content['print-link']['#theme']
```

or

```
$content['print_pdf']['#theme']
```

respectively. I even tried removing the ['#theme'] part but that didn't help.

Anyone know a good way to find the machine name of this variable that seems to have been added to $content but is not showing in admin > content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and use `dpm($content)` to inspect the content variable.

A good place to adjust the contents of a page in your theme is in a [preprocess](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430) function.

Comment: You're right about using devel; that helped me find it. Thank you.